# JavaScript - фильтр строк на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт на jquery, который при нажатии на кнопку делает remove для определенных тегов. 
Но он скрывает только те, которые не содержат `$("td").remove(".diffUnmodified");`.
Как удалить, в примере, и те заголовки, которые не содержат выделенных красным строк, но при этом оставить заголовок, который относится к выделенным ниже красным строкам.

Т.е из примера должно остаться только:

```
343344343434 

←dsfdfdsfdsffdsf 

←dfdfdsfsdfsdf
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("td").remove(".diffUnmodified");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Показать только различия</button><p>

</p><font color="blue">12334</font><br>
 <table class="diff">
<tr>
<td class="diffUnmodified">&rarr;dfsdfsdfsdfsdf
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<font color="blue">dfffffff</font><br>
<table class="diff">
<tr>
<td class="diffUnmodified">&rarr;3333333
</td>
</tr>
</table><font color="blue">sdsdsdsdsd</font><br>
<table class="diff"><tr>
<td class="diffUnmodified">&rarr;33333333
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<font color="blue">333333333</font><br>
<table class="diff">
<tr>
<td class="diffUnmodified">&larr;dfdfdfdfdfdfddfdf
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="diff">
<tr>
<td class="diffUnmodified">&larr;33333333333
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="diff">
<tr>
<td class="diffUnmodified">&rarr;sdfsdfsdfdsfssdf
</td>
</tr><
</table>
<font color="blue">343344343434</font><br><font color="red">&larr;dsfdfdsfdsffdsf
</font><br><font color="red">&larr;dfdfdsfsdfsdf
</font><br>
<table class="diff">
<tr><td class="diffUnmodified">&rarr;rrrrrrrrrrrr
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="diff">
<tr>
<td class="diffUnmodified">&rarr;dfdfdfddfdf
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Этот кусок HTML абсолютно не читаемый чтоб в нем разобраться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для красных ищет их первый синий который выше(сосед слева), дает ему класс `no-remove` и удаляет всех у кого нет такого класса.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        const red = $('font[color="red"]')
        red.each(function () {
          $(this).prevAll('font[color="blue"]').first().addClass('no-remove')
        })
        $('.diff').remove()
        $('font[color="blue"]').not('.no-remove').remove()
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Показать только различия</button><p>

</p><font color="blue">12334</font><br>
 <table class="diff">
<tr>
<td class="diffUnmodified">&rarr;dfsdfsdfsdfsdf
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<font color="blue">dfffffff</font><br>
<table class="diff">
<tr>
<td class="diffUnmodified">&rarr;3333333
</td>
</tr>
</table><font color="blue">sdsdsdsdsd</font><br>
<table class="diff"><tr>
<td class="diffUnmodified">&rarr;33333333
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<font color="blue">333333333</font><br>
<table class="diff">
<tr>
<td class="diffUnmodified">&larr;dfdfdfdfdfdfddfdf
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="diff">
<tr>
<td class="diffUnmodified">&larr;33333333333
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="diff">
<tr>
<td class="diffUnmodified">&rarr;sdfsdfsdfdsfssdf
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<font color="blue">343344343434</font><br><font color="red">&larr;dsfdfdsfdsffdsf
</font><br><font color="red">&larr;dfdfdsfsdfsdf
</font><br>
<table class="diff">
<tr><td class="diffUnmodified">&rarr;rrrrrrrrrrrr
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="diff">
<tr>
<td class="diffUnmodified">&rarr;dfdfdfddfdf
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```